# Angular localStorage array keeps getting reset on page refresh

Tags: angularjs, arrays

Objective:

I want the  localStorage cached  answers array to be prepopulated only by the contents of the 4 object  var questions array  the first time it is loaded
on subsequent page refreshes I want the modified localStorage answers array to be loaded  e.g. there may be many more objects or spliced objects in array

At the moment every time I page refresh it reverts back to the original  4 object array .

```
 var questions = [{"id":9,"Index":9,"Answered":"No","Correct":"?"},{"id":10,"Index":10,"Answered":"No","Correct":"?"},{"id":11,"Index":11,"Answered":"No","Correct":"?"},{"id":12,"Index":12,"Answered":"No","Correct":"?"}];

// storing our array as a string
localStorage.setItem("answers", JSON.stringify(questions));

// retrieving our data and converting it back into an array

var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("answers");


// Possible Solution  this intial array  gets created every time the page refreshes and needs some logic to determine 
// if it's intial length if not choose existing localstorage answers array in cache             

   $scope.answers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('answers'))




   $scope.addAnswer = function (){
    $scope.answers.push({"id":10,"Index":10,"Answered":"Yes","Correct":"Correct"})
        $scope.newAnswer = ''
    }

   $scope.spliceAnswer = function (){
    $scope.answers.splice(1, 1, {"id":10,"Index":10,"Answered":"Yes","Correct":"InCorrect"})
    $scope.replaceAnswer = ''
  }



   $scope.$watch('answers',function(newValue, oldValue){
    if(newValue!=oldValue){
        localStorage.setItem('answers',JSON.stringify(newValue))
    }
}, true)
```

HTML

```
<form name="frm" ng-submit="addAnswer()">
    <input type="text" name="newAnswer" ng-model="newAnswer" required />
    <button >Add </button>
</form>
<form name="frm" ng-submit="spliceAnswer()">
<input type="text" name="replaceAnswer" ng-model="replaceAnswer" required />
<button >Replace </button>
</form>             
<h6>Answers : {answers}</h6>
```

Comment: Could you tidy up your codes please? You asked 37 questions but only marked one right answer, why?

Comment: on line 4 instead of assigning directly to local storage first check if value is present for that key

Comment: if (localStorage.getItem("answers") === null) {
  
  $scope.answers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('answers')) }    Would this work ?

Comment: yes it should work

Comment: $scope.size = 0;
 $scope.size = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('answers'))).length
    $scope.$watch('size', function () {
        if ($scope.size = 0) {
          localStorage.setItem("answers", JSON.stringify(questions));
   $scope.answers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('answers')) 
        } else {
    $scope.answers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('answers')) 
 $scope.size = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('answers'))).length;;
        }
    });   I've tried to control it using $scope.size to no avail

Answer (score 0):

I think problem lies here :

```
if(newValue!=oldValue){
    localStorage.setItem('answers',JSON.stringify(newValue))
}
```

validate your new and old values also, change it to:

```
if(newValue && oldValue && newValue!=oldValue){
    localStorage.setItem('answers',JSON.stringify(newValue))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
              $scope.key = ($cookieStore.get('arraySize')) ? ($cookieStore.get('arraySize')) :0 ;




$scope.$watch('key', function () {
    if($scope.key == 0) {
        localStorage.setItem("answers", JSON.stringify(questions));
    } else{
        $scope.answers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('answers'));
    }
});


          $scope.$watch('answers',function(newValue, oldValue){
                if(newValue!=oldValue){
                    localStorage.setItem('answers',JSON.stringify(newValue))
                    $scope.size = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('answers'))).length;
                    $cookieStore.put( 'arraySize' , $scope.size );

                }
            }, true)

            $scope.arrayLength = $cookieStore.get('arraySize');

            $scope.key = parseInt($cookieStore.get('arraySize'));
```